# CUDA Reduction Optimization Example

Tags: optimization, cuda, nvidia, reduction

I am trying to implement the optimizations at [CUDA Reduction](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) and was to successfully complete till part 6. Thanks to all of you for helping me out. In order to get a complete feel with CUDA, I need to finish the final optimization as well, as mentioned in slide #31, known as algorithm cascading.

The idea is essentially to have 512 elements per thread and sum all of them up sequentially before performing the reduction.

I tried with a approach, where each thread of mine was accessing continuous 512 numbers from memory. Unfortunately, its performance was worst. I am guessing a reason to be bank conflicts but still haven't figured out exactly. Can any one of you suggest a reason for this behavior?

I am also posting the sample code provided by Nvidia below.

```
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + threadIdx.x;
unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
sdata[tid] = 0;
while (i < n) {
    sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize];
    i += gridSize;
}
__syncthreads();
```

Several parameters have been left undefined. I can infer that the blockSize is equal to number of threads per block. But I am unable to infer the importance of the variable 'gridSize'. What is the appropriate way of accessing the memory so that we get better performance? Is this an example of strided access?

Thank you in advance for help and comment below if you have any other questions.

Comment: Fully worked examples for all of these reductions codes are provided in the corresponding [CUDA sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction).  You shouldn't have to guess about any parameters.   I doubt you have provided enough information to explain your observation.  If your implementation of part 6 doesn't perform well, perhaps you should run the CUDA sample code and study the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have `blockDim.x = blockSize = 256` threads per block, and `gridDim.x = 32` blocks in the grid, and you want to reduce a large array `g_idata[8,192,000]`.

Then you have 8192 threads in total. Let's use

```
thread[x][y], x=0..31, y=0..255
```

to represent these threads.

Each `thread[x][y]` is loading

```
g_idata[iter*512*x+y] and g_idata[iter*512*x+256+y], iter = 0 .. 999
```

to the shared memory `sdata`.

For each iteration `iter`, all 8192 `threads[x][y]` will load `gridSize = 16384` elements from GPU memory.

This is coalesced memory access, and it is the correct way of accessing GPU memory.

However your way, where each `thread[x]` reads `data[i*x*512 .. i*(x+1)*512-1], i=0...` is not a good way. Actually it is the most inefficient possible way to access the GPU memory.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I thought the code is Nvidia demo, not Rahul's way. This one is: `I tried with a approach, where each thread of mine was accessing continuous 512 numbers from memory.`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer.  Deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is an example of coalesced access. The best gridDim depends on your hardware. Depending on the registers per thread and maximum threads per block, this value should be some multiplier of the number of multiprocessors available on your hardware. If your problem is large enough, 8 times multiprocessor count is a good pick for Kepler, and 16x for Maxwell.